# How to define reference to compress and uncompress in Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to compile a C program under Android. But I am getting 'compress' 'uncompress' when linking:

```
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/EXECUTABLES/androidvncserver_intermediates/LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rfbserver.o: in function rfbSendFileTransferChunk:external/android-vnc-server-read-only/LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rfbserver.c:1364: error: undefined reference to 'compress'
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/EXECUTABLES/androidvncserver_intermediates/LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rfbserver.o: in function rfbProcessFileTransfer:external/android-vnc-server-read-only/LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rfbserver.c:1626: error: undefined reference to 'uncompress'
```

I have already added in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libz
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libjpeg

LOCAL_MODULE:= androidvncserver
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz
```

Please let me know what am I missing:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    fbvncserver.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/main.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rfbserver.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rfbregion.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/auth.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/sockets.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/stats.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/corre.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/hextile.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/rre.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/translate.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/cutpaste.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/httpd.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/cursor.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/font.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/draw.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/selbox.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/d3des.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/vncauth.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/cargs.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/minilzo.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/ultra.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/scale.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/zlib.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/zrle.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/zrleoutstream.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/zrlepalettehelper.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/zywrletemplate.c \
    LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver/tight.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/LibVNCServer-0.9.7/libvncserver \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/LibVNCServer-0.9.7 \
    external/zlib \
    external/jpeg

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libz
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libjpeg

LOCAL_MODULE:= androidvncserver
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually doing in the following way:
Try to look at the rfbserver.c to the line 1364. Try to find 'compress' there and the definition of this variable (or macros or smth like this). Then try to find the definition of this variable in the include files. When you find them include this file into the project.